# Xcode Error: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GrowingTextView", referenced from, while I am compiling

Tags: ios, xcode

I added HpGrowingTextView open source to my program.
While i am compiling app, I got this error:

> compilation error: _OBJC_CLASS_$_HPGrowingTextView", referenced from:

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the files are added to target of project. If you are using a '.a file' for that, check if that is added to xcode.

Go to target -> build phases -> compile sources and check if the HPGrowingTextView .m files are added there. If not first make sure it is present in Xcode project and then drag and drop to here.